# onlick event detect double click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Im new here, my problem is that Im trying to play music or another sound with an onclick event, the problem begin when I try to stop that sound, I expect that the sound stop, but the sound begin ring again, here is the javascript code:

```
const playToPause = document.getElementById("play-song");

// main audio functions
function playSound() {
    const audio = new Audio("track_path");
    addEventListener("click", _ => {
        switch (playToPause.value) {
            case "pause":
                audio.play();
                playToPause.value = "play";
                break;
            case "play":
                audio.pause();
                playToPause.value = "pause"
        }
        console.log(playToPause.value);
    });
};
```

And here is the button element

```
<button id="play-song" value="pause" onclick="playSound()" class="fa-solid fa-play fa-3x action-buttons"></button>
```

i had try before with if...else if, sentence and i changed it by a switch sentence thinking that the problem was on if...else if.

Later I use a console.log to see the value of the button and I get this the first time that I click it:browser console as code tag with "```")

the console show that:
`play                            jquery.client.js:16`

But if I click again on the button, to stop the sound, it detect as a double click

The console show that:

```
play                            jquery.client.js:16 (The first click)
pause                           jquery.client.js:16
play                            jquery.client.js:16
```

Sorry, for my bad english, I hope that anyone can help thanks in advance :)

Comment: You add a new click event listener to the `window` object, every time the `playSound()` function is called (which is every time you click on the button). Those stack. What is the point of the `addEventListener()` anyway when you already use an `onclick="playSound()"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're redefining the `audio` variable each time the function is executing - with the result that the `audio.play()` or `audio.pause()` is playing or pausing that just-created sound. It does nothing with any that were previously playing.

To fix, just move the definition of `audio` outside the function.

Also, as @Ivar says in his comment, your `addEventListener` should not be inside the function, or you add new listeners each time. Your function will already run each time the button is clicked because of the inline `onclick` attribute on the button.

So change your code to this:

```
const playToPause = document.getElementById("play-song");
const audio = new Audio("track_path");

// main audio functions
function playSound() {
    switch (playToPause.value) {
        case "pause":
            audio.play();
            playToPause.value = "play";
            break;
        case "play":
            audio.pause();
            playToPause.value = "pause"
    }
    console.log(playToPause.value);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- User Audio Tag -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <audio id="audio-tag">
        <source src="./partham-ganesh-besado-re.mp3" type="audio/ogg">
        <source src="./partham-ganesh-besado-re.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>

    <button onclick="play()" type="button">Play</button>
    <button onclick="pause()" type="button">Pause</button>

    <script>
        var audio = document.getElementById("audio-tag");

        function play() {
            audio.play();
        }

        function pause() {
            audio.pause();
        } 
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: It's Simply make tow button, one for Play and one for pause, if you click on play btn then it start audio, and if you press pause button then it will pause the video